# jQuery load() gives empty results with Greasemonkey

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to load an external page and parse the HTML:

```
var $f = jQuery().load("http://google.com");
alert($f.text());
```

But the alert box doesn't show anything, and length is zero.

I'm using Greasemonkey 0.9.13 and jQuery 1.7.1

What am I doing wrong?

---

Note from OP comment, below: `"script is executed from same domain. google is only an example"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, jQuery `load()` (and most other jQuery AJAX) does not work cross domain.  You say that's not a factor here, but it will be in the future or for others.

The more immediate problem with that code:

```
var $f = jQuery().load("http://google.com");
alert($f.text());
```

Is that `load()` is not synchronous.  That first line of code starts a process but execution immediately drops to the `alert()` statement -- long before the `load()` process finishes.

**Get around both problems by using [GM_xmlhttpRequest()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest)**.

So your code would become:

```
var pageText;

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:         'GET',
    url:            'http://google.com',
    onload:         function (responseDetails) {
                        pageText = responseDetails.responseText;

                        //-- This will alert the page contents.
                        alert (pageText);
                    }
} );

//--- This will alert nothing.
alert (pageText);
```

Just be sure to process the text inside the `onload` handler.

---

---

If you really must have the code wait for the loaded page (*not* recommended), you can use the `synchronous` flag, like so:

```
var pageText;

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:         'GET',
    url:            'http://google.com',
    onload:         function (responseDetails) {
                        pageText = responseDetails.responseText;

                        //-- This will alert the page contents.
                        alert (pageText);
                    },
    synchronous:    true
} );

/*--- This will also alert the text, but the page/GM script can appear 
    to "freeze" for a bit.
*/
synchronous:    true
alert (pageText);
```

Comment: this way is better than jquery load(). But now I've other problem, I explain here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753245/gm-xmlhttprequest-loses-data-in-jquery-each-statement

Answer (score 2):

Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), most AJAX requests cannot successfully retrieve data from a different domain. (The external server must be setup to specifically facilitate cross-domain requests.). [See the notes](http://api.jquery.com/load/#notes-0) in the API spec for `.load()`.

**Edit:** If some origin policy is followed, your JS still isn't quite right. `.load()` doesn't return the AJAX result, it inserts it into the preceding element in the chain. So:

```
var $f = $('div');
    $f.load("/somepath", function() {
        // do something with the subtree of $f
    });
```

Comment: I reading about that.
but, script is executed from same domain. google is only an example

Comment: Oh okay. In that case, see my edit for a working version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work at all if it's cross domain, unless you use `gm_xmlhttprequest` but if it's not you can accomplish what you're trying with the following:

```
$.get('http://google.com', function(data) {
    alert($(data).text());
});
```

Comment: thanks... but this doesn't work, alert box doesn't appear.
apparently the way is to use gm_xmlhttprequest